# Trying to hyperlink a word that is inside a footnote using RMarkdown

Tags: hyperlink, r-markdown, footnotes

I am using Rmarkdown to generate a PDF. I am trying to hyperlink the word `Figure 1` that is inside of a footnote, but the issue is that it ends up hyperlinking everything in the footnote. I'm guessing this is due to a clash because the syntax with Hyperlinks and Footnotes are quite similar, is there a way around this?

```
^[I only want to hyperlink the word [Figure 1](\ref{Fig1}) in this footnote.]
```

TIA